# How to read a shared table of DolphinDB with Orca?

Tags: database, pandas, load, dolphindb

I wonder if I can read data from a DolphinDB shared table in Python client with Orca. I used to read shared table by running DolphinDB script with DolphinDB Python API in this way:

```py
import dolphindb as ddb
s=ddb.session()
s.connect("127.0.0.1", 8848)
df=s.run("select * from tb") #tb refers to the table name which I have already defined on DolphinDB Server
```

But the data retrieved are stored in a pandas DataFrame rather than an Orca DataFrame.And it consumes time to transform it into an Orca DataFrame. So, is there a function in Orca for loading data from a DOlphinDB shared table into a Orca object ?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import dolphindb.orca as orca
orca.connect("localhost",8848,"admin","123456")
tb = orca.read_table('dfs://db','tb')
```